# SSH connections not accepted after configuring NFS?

Tags: ssh, nfs, amazon-ec2

I have a couple of servers in a VPC in Amazon EC2. One of them acts as a NFS server, and one of them as a client.

I recently noticed a problem in the client that after a reboot, it would reject all SSH connections, presumably because SSH was not running. After transferring the EBS volume to another instance and taking a peek inside, I commented out the NFS line in `/etc/fstab` and tried attaching it back to the server and booting it. Lo and behold, I was able to connect with SSH.

It seems that having the following line in my fstab is breaking everything on boot:

```
10.0.0.1:/export/share /mnt/shared nfs auto 0 0
```

Why is this causing SSH to fail to start? How can I have NFS automatically mount on boot without breaking networking/SSH on the system?

I've checked that `sudo mount -a` works properly, so it seems that there isn't an inherent problem in the fstab command. What's breaking and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does disabling automounting, then manually mounting it after SSH has loaded successfully also break SSH?

Comment: Nope, it only breaks on boot when it's in fstab.

Comment: Does the SSH init script actually run?

Comment: What ami are you using?  The latest RHEL or something else?  I found a bug in the latest RHEL image in rc.local that was causing ssh to fail to start on reboot.  After I fixed that things were good.  A bad nfs config should not conflict with SSH as long as you're not clobbering your home directory preventing access to your ssh credentials

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more option when mounting `nfs` , we always use this

Example

```
10.0.0.1:/export/share /mnt/shared nfs _netdev,noatime,intr,auto 0 0
```

These are mount options : 'noatime' improves access rate, and 'auto' tells the Rpi to aumount the NFS shares on startup.

from `man mount`

> _netdev The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these
>   filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).

Comment: Even with that exact line in my fstab, SSH doesn't start up. Comment it out, and it starts.

Comment: what is sequence in `fstab`, is that nfs entry at last ?

Comment: Yes, it's at the last entry in fstab.

Comment: have you find any error in logs `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Nope, nothing significant in there.

Comment: @TKKocheran have you tried with mounting `nfs4`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nobootwait` or `nofail` as mount options in the fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with nfs shares mounted on a remote server. nfs is going through openvpn.

I tried load of things, nothing worked, included hints above. options in fstab like `_netdev,ro,noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=openvpn.service,x-systemd.device-timeout=30 0 0` did not work.

In `rc3.d` I tried different services order...

The only very dirty solution I found was to use `_netdev,ro,noauto,nofail   0   0` option in fstab just to make sure it ignores those nfs shares if they do not mount correctly at boot up and added a line in `rc.local` to mount the shares like `mount 192.168.0.1:/myshare`